# OPENUI5\SAPUI5 code coverage in OPA5

Tags: javascript, code-coverage, qunit, sapui5

I have the next application structure:

[image]

When i run the MyControl.qunit.html its OK and the test is green, but when i run the code coverage, its working.

But it doesn't cover my code in MyControl control that defined in the MyControllerApp.view.xml file.

The problem is that the code coverage doesn't cover the code in the OPA tested application.

Any help guys?

Thanks

Comment: i have the same issue. Maybe this brings you further: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782622/code-coverage-in-sapui5-opa5-tests
?

Comment: @samba2 please look at this guys comment - its the answer, thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Code coverage in sapui5 OPA5 tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782622/code-coverage-in-sapui5-opa5-tests)